# How to remove not useful elements from a dataset

Tags: python, json, preprocessor

I have a dataset, and it look like the following:

```
 {0: {"address": 0,
         "ctag": "TOP",
         "deps": defaultdict(<class "list">, {"ROOT": [6, 51]}),
         "feats": "",
         "head": "",
         "lemma": "",
         "rel": "",
         "tag": "TOP",
         "word": ""},
     1: {"address": 1,
         "ctag": "Ne",
         "deps": defaultdict(<class "list">, {"NPOSTMOD": [2]}),
         "feats": "_",
         "head": 6,
         "lemma": "اشرف",
         "rel": "SBJ",
         "tag": "Ne",
         "word": "اشرف"},
```

I want to remove `"deps":...?` from this dataset. I tried this code but does not work, because the value of `"depts":` differ in each element of the dict.

```
import re
import simplejson as simplejson

with open("../data/cleaned.txt", 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    k = str(lines)
    a = re.sub(r'\d:', '', k) # this is for removing numbers like `1:{..`
    json_data = simplejson.dumps(a)
    #print(json_data)
    n = eval(k.replace('defaultdict(<class "list">', 'list'))
    print(n)
```

Comment: Try to load the whole json into a dictionary instead of using `json.dumps()` and then `pop` the key.

Comment: This is not valid Json. How did you produce a *text* file containing that?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I used the dependency parser, and it produces this data, I want to adjust into JSON format, but how?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, Why did you delete your solution?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the behaviour you showed in your comments, so I assumed that the answer was not helpful. Of course I can undelete it, but I really think that this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/397459)...

Comment: @SergeBallesta, But your suggestion helped me to reach some result. Just one problem was left, I am searching for that, the `repr` function, add `\n` to the file. The rest was great. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way would be to fix the code that produced the text file. This `defaultdict(<class "list">, {"ROOT": [6, 51]})` is a hint that it used a simple `repr` when a smarter format was required.

The following is just a poor man's workaround if the real fix is not possible.

Getting rid of `"deps": ...` is easy: it is enough to read the file one line at a time and discard any one starting with `""deps"` (ignoring initial white spaces). But it is not enough, because the file contains numeric keys when json insist on keys being only text. So the numerics key must be identified and quoted.

This could allow to load the file:

import re
import simplejson as simplejson

```
with open("../data/cleaned.txt", 'r') as fp:
    k = ''.join(re.sub(r'(?<!\w)(\d+)', r'"\1"',line)
        for line in fp if not line.strip().startswith('"deps"'))

# remove an eventual last comma
k = re.sub(r',[\s\n]*$', '', k, re.DOTALL)

# uncomment if the file does not contain the last }
# k += '}'

js = json.loads(k)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it gives this error, `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 15 (char 14)`, even I include the `':'` in the regex, but still this error. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: @user2988094: Cannot reproduce. Can you show what gives `print(repr(k[:20]))` just before using `loads`?

Comment: it gives me the first line as this: `'  [         {""0"": ' ` and if I use `print(repr(k[:])) `gives me all output but not in odered.

Comment: Where does the `[` come from? And how can you have lines with my code?

Comment: The output looks like:  `{""0"": {"address": "0",\n                 "ctag": "TOP",\n                 "feats": "",\n                 "head": "",\n                 "lemma": "",\n                 "rel": "",\n                 "tag": "TOP",\n                 "word": ""},\n `

Comment: I added in the begining and end of file, I thought if it can load, now I remove it back.

Comment: Just how to give it back the same structure, I mean each element on its line.

Comment: If you do not show the actual content of the input file, or do not use my code, I won't be able to help you... A file containing what is shown in the question and processed with the code in that answer cannot give **2** double quotes around first `0`.

Comment: And if I write it with JSON back to a JSON file, `
with open('../data/data.json', 'wt') as fj:`
           ` json.dump(repr(k[:]), fj)` it wrote like:` it gives me this structure: `{""0"": {"address": "0",\n                 "ctag": "TOP",\n                 "feats": "",\n                 "head": "",\n                 "lemma": "",\n                 "rel": "",\n                 "tag": "TOP",\n                 "word": ""},\n`

Comment: Can you tell me why `'\n'` is added to each element, and now I can not replace it. How to solve this? I searched a lot but could not find any solution.

Comment: Just strip it out from the individual lines before the join: `k = ''.join(re.sub(r'(?<!\w)(\d+)', r'"\1"',line.rstrip())
        for line in fp if not line.strip().startswith('"deps"'))`. I left them because they are harmless in a Json string.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
import json
with open("../data/cleaned.txt", 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
    for key, value in data.items():
        value.pop("deps", None)
```

Now you will have data without `deps` in it. In case if you want to dump the records to a new file

```py
json.dump(data, "output.json")
```

Comment: the code you shared gives me two error. First, if I include the `"deps": defaultdict(<class "list">, {"NPOSTMOD": [2]})` in the dataset, gives error on the `:defaultdict(<class "list">, ` and if I remove this part, it gives this eroor:  `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

data = {0: {"address": 0,
            "ctag": "TOP",
            "deps": 'something',
            "feats": "",
            "head": "",
            "lemma": "",
            "rel": "",
            "tag": "TOP",
            "word": ""},
        1: {"address": 1,
            "ctag": "Ne",
            "deps": 'something',
            "feats": "_",
            "head": 6,
            "lemma": "اشرف",
            "rel": "SBJ",
            "tag": "Ne",
            "word": "اشرف"}}

for value in data.values():
    if 'deps' in value:
        del value['deps']
```

Comment: you edited the dataset,`"depts": 'something'`, where the actual look is  `"deps": defaultdict(<class "list">, {"ROOT": [6, 51]}),`, your code works on edited dataset, but not in actual case. How to solve with actual, while I used your code on the actual dataset, it gives me this error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 5 column 26 (char 107)` that points on the `dept`.

Comment: How the data is created. Can you share cleaned.txt?

Comment: Before the data is written to disk (as 'cleaned.txt' ) the 'deps' field should be converted to dict. `data['deps'] = dict(data['deps'])`

Comment: I used dependency parser, to parse the text and then I want to do the relation extraction on the Dari text. Now, the parser created this text, as you see in the post, but I have to change it into JSON format to get access for each element and then categorize. How to do it, it is a problem

Comment: Do you have control on the code that writes the 'cleaned.txt'? If you do  - see my comment above. Before the parser write to disk - the deps should be modified

Comment: No, it gives me this error while I changed it to dict, `TypeError: 'DependencyGraph' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I tried to convert the `cleaned.txt` to `dict`, it gives me this error ` ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) `