# Checking existence of two list elements in a dict based on each sentence?

Tags: python, json, nlp

I have a JSON file ...

```
  "1": {"address": "1",
          "ctag": "Ne",
          "feats": "_",
          "head": "6",
          "lemma": "Ghani",
          "rel": "SBJ",
          "tag": "Ne",
          "word": "Ghani"},
    "2": {"address": "2",
          "ctag": "AJ",
          "feats": "_",
          "head": "1",
          "lemma": "born",
          "rel": "NPOSTMOD",
          "tag": "AJ",
          "word": "born"},
    "3": {"address": "3",
          "ctag": "P",
          "feats": "_",
          "head": "6",
          "lemma": "in",
          "rel": "ADV",
          "tag": "P",
          "word": "in"},
    "4": {"address": "4",
          "ctag": "N",
          "feats": "_",
          "head": "3",
          "lemma": "Kabul",
          "rel": "POSDEP",
          "tag": "N",
          "word": "Kabul"},
  "5": {"address": "5",
          "ctag": "PUNC",
          "feats": "_",
          "head": "6",
          "lemma": ".",
          "rel": "PUNC",
          "tag": "PUNC",
          "word": "."},
```

I read the JSON file and stored in a dict.

```
import json

# read file
with open('../data/data.txt', 'r') as JSON_file:
     obj = json.load(JSON_file)

d = dict(obj) # stored it in a dict
```

I extracted two list from this `dict` that each list contains `relation` from text and `entities` as follow:

```
 entities(d) = ['Ghani', 'Kabul', 'Afghanistan'....]
 relation(d) = ['president', 'capital', 'located'...]
```

Now I want to check in each sentence of dict `d`, if any element of `entities(d)` and `relation(d)` exist, it should be stored to another list. 
What I did?

```
to_match = set(relation(d) + entities(d))
entities_and_relation = [[j for j in to_match if j in i] 
                    for i in ''.join(d).split('.')[:-1]]
print(entities_and_relation)
```

But this return me an empty list. Can you tell me what is wrong here.

OUTPUT should be like:
     [Ghani, president, Afghanistan] ...

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: What sentences are you refering to?

Comment: @Jeril, OUTPUT: `{Ghani, President, Afghanistan}` as it is in a sentence.

Comment: @Jab, to each sentence in the dataset, I refere, because the `relation(d)` and `entities(d)` are extracted from the sentences of the `d`.

Comment: How about putting a sample of what `d` is in the question along with expected output. We don't know what you're looking at on your screen and we can't read your mind.

Comment: I tried to make it simple, you can have a look to the dataset in this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042037/how-to-remove-not-useful-elements-from-a-dataset/55043065?noredirect=1#comment96844285_55043065).

Comment: @Jab, you can have a look to the question again. I change it to be able to read my mind. thanks

Comment: I see no sentences in this dictionary. This is also invalid JSON which will add another layer of difficulty to helping answer this question

Comment: We are trying to help, please just provide enough detail in the question with complete and verifiable examples. I am unable to discern how you define a sentence from the JSON provided. If you help us help you everything moves smoother

Comment: @Jab, Thanks for your help. if you look to the JSON file, this is the first sentence ended in `key:5`, the `tag:PUNC` or `'.'` present end of each sentence. I extracted two types of list from this dict, one includes the entities like `'Ghani, Kabul,..`, the second includes the relation between these entities, for example, in the dataset, it is one sentence that includes this text: `"Ghani born in Kabul"`.  and `born` is a relation and stored in `relation`. I did till the end of the dataset, now I want to check if from these two lists any element in d together in each sentence.

Comment: Unfortunately no. As going through your JSON I'm having trouble correlating each key to a respective value and it either being in another language it looks like, or very difficult to understand abbreviations is not helping. Neither are you making it very easy for me to want to continue my endeavor in helping you by being rude and sarcastic. We are all volunteers here we're not paid to help people and making a fuss about it is not going to get you answers more quickly if at all. Either way I wish you the best of luck and hope you figure this out. From here on I'm done helping with this question

Answer (score 0):

Here I solved this problem, but I don't know how to give it a specific format for each related entities.

```
for i in d.values():
if i['word'].split('.')[-1] in to_match:
    print('{: ^10}'.format(i['word']))
```

Output:

```
 Ghani
 Kabul
 Born
 Kabul
 Captial
 Afghanistan
```

My expected output:

```
 (Ghani, born, Kabul), (Kabul, capital, Afghanistan) or ...
 Born_in(Ghani, Kabul), Capital_of(Kabul, Afghanistan)
```

I don't know to map it or designed it to give me as expected output.

Comment: Can you `print` the contents of dictionary `d` and `to_match` list? I'll try to help format your expected output..

Comment: @davedwards, Thank you, the content of `d` is a JSON file as it is added in the question. It has all the words from the sentences. I extracted two list from `d`.  `1. entities list like [Ghani, Kabul, Afghanistan ...]`, and another list is `2.relations such as [born, located, president, ...]`. I stored both lists in `to_match'. I have to check each sentence if any `entities and relations` from `to_match` matched within one sentence, it should be extracted as `[Ghani, president, Afghanistan]` and more.

Comment: try this: `line = [];
for i in d.values():
    if i['word'].split('.')[-1].lower() in to_match:
        line.append(str(i['word']));
print(tuple(line));`. should display as `('Ghani', 'born', 'Kabul')` ?

Comment: @davedwards, thanks, but it prints in first loop one element, and in the second two elements, in third loops, three elements such as: `(Ghani),(Ghani, born), (Ghani, born, Kabul), (Ghani, born, Kabul, Kabul), (Ghani, born, Kabul, Kabul, capital...)`, each loop in new line. How to fix this?

Comment: de-indent the `print` line so it is out of the `for`-loop, like this: https://repl.it/@downshift/NoisyMintcreamObjectcode, press `run` button at the top of that page to see the output

Comment: @davedwards, THANK YOU. I appreciated your knowledge, last question, in your code, it show correct but in mine how to add from each sentence the entitie and relation in tuple such as: `(Ghani, born, Kabul), (Kabul, capital, Afghanistan)` but now it shows all in one tuple

Comment: yes, can you edit the code in the link to make it show your output please? thanks https://repl.it/@downshift/NoisyMintcreamObjectcode